# Gnome-terminal doesn't start

Tags: gnome-terminal

Gnome-terminal doesn't start when I click it from the dash. When I open x-term and try to start it from there, I get"floating point exception (core-dumped)". But I could start gnome-terminal as root. So what's going on? And how do I fix it?

Comment: I would advice filing a bug report towards gnome-terminal. I have not seen any error like this reported towards gnome-terminal so it might be something new.

Comment: and in the mean time, ctrl + alt + t

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen Why would `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T` help? On a GNOME-based desktop (like Unity), that will just open `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is one of the first pages that appears when searching for this problem, and there is no actual solution to it, I thought of posting one that worked for me.

-- This should only work if you tinkered with fonts by using Ubuntu Tweak --

So, if you did do that, go to MyUnity, go to the fonts tab, and select Default Settings. After the fonts have been returned to normal, the terminal will start working again.

At least that did the trick for me.

Props go to Knurveren for the [fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/990754/comments/5).

Cheers!

Comment: That was a nice and smarty fix! The font size was incorrectly set to "Inconsolata 0", and that was causing the problem. Setting good monospace font solves the problem! Though, The problematic app was guake

Answer (score 2):

Given your description, it is almost certain that `gnome-terminal` is starting, but always crashes. (You won't see the crash message if you start it from the dash.) I recommend [enabling Apport crash reporting](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport#How_to_enable_apport) and then reporting a bug. To report the bug, [read this page first](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), then try to run `gnome-terminal`, then let Apport submit information to Launchpad automatically and fill out the bug report in your web browser when it comes up.

The information sent to Launchpad when Apport automatically reports the crash is necessary for your bug report (for a crash, like this) to be useful. It's possible to manually generate this information, but there is very little reason to do so, since Apport does the job quite well.

Comment: Sure, I've already sent a bug report. In the meantime, I guess I'll try out guake

Answer (score 2):

For me what works is

```
gnome-terminal -x bash
```

then go to : preferences->profiles->edit->command and uncheck "run a custom command instead of my shell"

Hope it'll help you

Comment: Hahahah, thanks works like a charm, my command was also broken