# Update to 18.04 but terminal doesn't work

Tags: gnome-terminal, update-manager

From Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 but now terminal doesn't work. When I open terminal it loading and crash...

Comment: I already try with alt+f2 (gnome-terminal) and ctrl+alt+t but nothing

Comment: do you have `xterm` installed? Can you open that? If yes, what is the output when you type `gnome-terminal` ?

Comment: did you see this question and the answers to it? https://askubuntu.com/questions/127235/gnome-terminal-doesnt-start?rq=1

Comment: I think have same problem with fonts. I try to open Unity Tweak Tool but it say: com.canonical.notify-osd not found. But I can't to install it without terminal

Comment: Whit ctrl-alt-F7 open shell and install notify-osd. Open Unity Tweak Tool and set default fonts but nothing. Terminal doesn't work